# Separate changes in directory to a branch

Tags: git

I have directories `a` and `b` in my source code. In `master`, I have commits that contain changes in both directories mixed.

Is it possible (and easy) to create branch `a` whose commits contain only changes in directory `a` and branch `b` dtto with directory `b`? Commit messages would be the same, empty commits (only containing changes in the other directory formely) would disappear.

I know I could use `git rebase -i`, but that would be a lot of manual work for me.

Comment: You can use filter-branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (assumes you are on master):

```
git checkout -b a
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf b' HEAD
git checkout -b b master
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'rm -rf a' HEAD
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
```

Comment: Do you need `--prune-empty` with this?

Comment: Why would you need `--prune-empty`?  I tried this and found it did what I expected.

Comment: If the only thing committed in the first `filter-branch` operation was something in `b/`, wouldn't removing `b/` lead to a commit with nothing in it? That's what `--prune-empty` is for, according to [the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html). Maybe it doesn't apply with `--tree-filter`?